# Showing name of row instead of excel cell name

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I am having extremely long formulas over an extremely big sheet. At the moment I am tracking the formulas with the `Formula Auditing` Tool. However, my idea would be to just replace for example in a formula like this:

`=IF(AND(ROUND($GX19-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0;$AK$7=1);0;$M$12*$M$22/$K$62`

My idea would be to replace the excel cell names with the table row names they are in. Like:

`=IF(AND(ROUND( "Income" -SUM(0)/ "Debt" ;2)<=0; "Percentage" =1);0; "Investment" * "Debt of house" / "Investment costs"`

Is there any way to achive sth. like that in excel?

I appreciate your inputs!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would convert your range to a Table (Insert Ribbon, Table).  In that format, the cell references in formulas will tend to be structured references, using the column name (from the heading row).

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-HA010155686.aspx

I noticed you mentioned row names, so you may have to swap your rows and columns.  But there are so many other benefits to using Tables (not just references) so it is usually worth the effort.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I converted it into a structured table, but my formulas are still of the old form of, `=IF(AND(ROUND($GX19-SUM(0)/$M$12;2)<=0;$AK$7=1);0;$M$12*$M$22/$K$62` Any recommendations for that?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Use names. Go to cell $GX19, press CTRL-F3, choose add a named range, and type Income as the name. Whenever you refer to GX19 from now on it will use the named range instead. You'll have to replace your existing forumulae, I'd do this one by one just by standard search and replace in formulae (CTRL-H).